# Karma test case giving error on importing a service which uses a globally available interface

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-test

**Error on console**: src/app/services/auth/login.service.ts(27,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LoginModel'.

I will be mentioning the following files ->

1. app/components/login/login.component.ts
2. app/components/login/login.component.spec.ts
3. app/components/login/login.model.ts

and

4. app/services/login.service.ts

**login.model.ts** contains

```
interface LoginModel {
    success: boolean;
}
```

**login.service.ts** contains (uses the LoginModel in it)

```
      import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { UtilityService } from '../../shared/util/utility.service';
import { map } from '../../../../node_modules/rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  private username;
  private password;
  // store the URL so we can redirect after logging in
  public redirectUrl: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private utils: UtilityService) { }

  attemptLogin(username, password) {
    this.username = username.trim();
    this.password = password;
    return this.http.post(<post_body>, {}, {}).pipe(
      map((data: LoginModel) => {

      }));
  }
}
```

So here it is using the interface defined above (no import or export is happening here)

**login.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from '../../../services/auth/login.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // reset login status
    this.loginService.logOut().toPromise().then(data => console.log('Logged Out Successfully'));

    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('tetsing', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('testing', [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
}
```

**spec file** contains

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginService } from './../../../services/auth/login.service';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
let component: LoginComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [ LoginComponent ],

  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create instance', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

Now, when I run this test case, it gives error of not knowing what `LoginModel` (the type used in login service) is. How do I make it available for the test case?

Comment: Post your error trace and **your whole code** please.

Comment: pls check now, this is the max content I can share

Comment: Yeah but now you removed the spec file ...

Comment: I added it back. You didn't provide your service into your testbed, is that desired ?

Comment: Also, please post your error trace.

Comment: posted it in first line, and yes login service will be needed since i am making a test case for it

Comment: Even if I do not use login service in the test case, it is being imported in Login component, and that also gives the same error

Comment: export your interface like so: `export interface LoginModel { ... }`

Comment: Sorry but I can't change the code written by someone else. I am only supposed to work on testing part. The application otherwise is working fine